# BrainTree Sandbox returns Validation errors: - Unknown paymentMethodNonce

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, braintree

I am integrating braintree into a website

starting with the sandbox....

client side:

```
   <form id="checkout" method="post" action="payments.php">
  <div id="dropin"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay $10">
</form>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>

<script>
  braintree.setup(
    // Replace this with a client token from your server

    "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",
    'dropin', {
      container: 'dropin'
    });
</script>
```

and for the server:

```
 <?php
include("braintree/Braintree.php"); 

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('');

$nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
  'amount' => '100.00',
  'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce
));


if ($result->success) {
    echo("Success! Transaction ID: " . $result->transaction->id);
} else if ($result->transaction) {
    echo("Error: " . $result->message);
    echo("<br/>");
    echo("Code: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
} else {
    echo("Validation errors:<br/>");
    foreach (($result->errors->deepAll()) as $error) {
        echo("- " . $error->message . "<br/>");
    }
}
```

and when it returns:

```
 Validation errors: - Unknown paymentMethodNonce.
```

this was code taken directly from the tutorial - so confused what it is I did wrong

this is a website only (no app) service

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear which client token you used in the JS and which merchant credentials you used in the PHP but I think this is probably the problem.

Payment method nonces are merchant-specific, and the client token initializes the Drop In UI with limited permission to act on behalf of a specific merchant. If you used the actual client token pasted above, this merchant was our sandbox demo merchant.

You need to substitute your own sandbox merchant's merchant ID, public key and private key in the fields at the top of your PHP sample (I assume you did and just took them out for posting). You also need to call Braintree::ClientToken.generate within your PHP when building the page that displays the UI so that you can add a real client token for your merchant to that page.  See https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/start/hello-server#provide-a-client-token-to-your-client.

Feel free to contact Braintree Support at support@braintreepayments.com [support@braintreepayments.com](http://mailto://support@braintreepayments.com)if you'd like more help.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass a valid nonce. eq:fake-valid-nonce.

Other valid nonces are here in [braintree page link](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/php#test-amounts)